# Convert decimal month and year into Date

Tags: r, date, yearmonth

I have a 'decimal month' and a year variable:

`df <- data.frame(decimal_month = c(4.75, 5, 5.25), year = c(2011, 2011, 2011))`

How can I convert these variables to a `Date`? (`"2011-04-22" "2011-05-01" "2011-05-08"`). Or at least to day of the year.

Comment: Can you show the exact expected output?

Comment: df<-data.frame(day_of_the_year=c(112, 121, 127))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use some nice functions from the `zoo` package:

`as.yearmon` to convert year and `floor` of the decimal month to class `yearmon`.

Then use `as.Date.yearmon` and its `frac` argument to coerce the year-month to class `Date`.

```
library(zoo)
df$date = as.Date(as.yearmon(paste(df$year, floor(df$decimal_month), sep = "-")),
                  frac = df$decimal_month - floor(df$decimal_month))

#       decimal_month year        date
# 1              4.75 2011  2011-04-22
# 2              5.00 2011  2011-05-01
# 3              5.25 2011  2011-05-08
```

If desired, day of year is simply `format(df$date, "%j")`